# How to use rust module inside a different test directory?

Tags: rust

This is my directory structure,

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── add.rs
│   └── main.rs
└── tests
    └── add_test.rs
```

`add.rs`

```
pub fn add(a: u8, b: u8) -> u8 {
  return a + b;
}
```

`main.rs`

```
pub mod add;

fn main() {}
```

`add_test.rs`

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
  #[test]
  fn add_test() {
    // how do I use add.rs module?
  }
}
```

In `add_test` function how do I test `add.rs`'s `add` function?

Comment: `pub mod add`? anything internal to the library cannot be tested from outside iirc.

Comment: You don't need `#[cfg(test)]` in `tests/[test-file].rs`, Just `#[test]` would be enough... See more about [Integration testing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/integration_testing.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that you are using `mod add;`. This is not a public module meaning it is unavailable outside of your crate.

To have it available outside the crate (and therefore available in the test) you can either make the module public, or reexport the function itself.
Additionally, to do this, you will need a `lib.rs` file in `src` where the exports are put:

```rust
// Make module public
pub mod add; 

// Make the function available at the root of the crate
pub use add::add;
```

To then use your function in tests, you call it the same way you would call a function for a different crate. Lets assume your crate was named `your-crate`:

```rust
// If your module is public
your-crate::add::add(2,3);

// If you reexport the function
your-crate::add(2,3);
```

See more details in [the chapter on test organization in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html).

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that. But the main questions is how do I use `add` inside `tests/add_test.rs`?

Comment: Editted with how to call it.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to Rust but what is `my-crate`? Do you mean `use crate::`?

Comment: I changed it to `your-crate`. It just the name of your rust project. Often its just the folder name, but you can see it in the `cargo.toml` under `name`.

Comment: In my case the name in `Cargo.toml` is `ru`. So it should be `ru::add::add(2, 3)` right? If that is so then it says `failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module ru`.

Comment: Ah, you are using `main.rs` which means your crate is a binary crate. If you make a `lib.rs` file additionally and export the modules the same way as you are doing now in `main.rs` it should work. I'll update the answer

Comment: Just use [rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/), It has [auto import](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#auto-import) functionality.

Comment: I created a lib.rs with main.rs. I needed that anyway. Thank you all for your help.